# Android: Time stored in db is not the same as on phone

Tags: java, android

I'm using System.currentTimeMillis(); to get the current time for my 'modified' db field. I'm converting it to unix epoch by dividing it by 1000.
However, even when the phone's / emulator's date and time are set to true time, the value stored in the db is 2 hours earlier than true time.

I'm in GMT+2, but I can't find how this is affecting.

Doesn't System.currentTimeMillis(); get the current time for the current time settings ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use Calendar.getInstance() instead, as this:

```
Calendar curTime = Calendar.getInstance();
```

This `curTime` object will be locale-specific.

From the API, in regards to currentTimeMillis()

> This method shouldn't be used for measuring timeouts or other elapsed time measurements, as changing the system time can affect the results.

Answer (score 2):

[`currentTimeMillis`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis%28%29) doesn't return timezone-dependent timestamps:

> the difference, measured in milliseconds, between the current time and midnight, January 1, 1970 **UTC**.

However, it is good practice to store timestamps in UTC and to **not** include timezone offsets. To display the "correct" time, you can use a [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html):

```
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
// set your Timezone; or use TimeZone.getDefault() for the device timezone
df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Paris"));
String time = df.format(new Date(timestamp));
```

Answer (score 0):

From [the documentation:](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis%28%29)

> "returns the difference, measured in milliseconds, between the current time and midnight, January 1, 1970 UTC"

It gives you the time, independant from your time zone. So you should calculate the correct time yourself.